# Wrong orientation of a figure

Tags: floats, rotating, figure-placement

I want to insert a figure using the package  `graphicx`   . But the orientation of the figure  is not correct: The figure I want to insert is `3*4`, but in the pdf it rotates 90 degrees automatically and becomes `4*3`. Why would this happen and how can I fix it?

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{fig.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `graphicx` package provides quite a few macros -- which one, or which ones, do you employ? Please edit your posting to provide a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that replicates the issue you wish to fix.

Comment: `\includegraphics` will not rotate the image unless you specify rotation, but some pdf viewers will "auto rotate" the view if they spot text or other things that they decide should rotate. Any such rotation is an artifact of the view like zoom level, not intrisic part of the pdf file

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use the `subfigure` package -- it's been obsolete for nearly two decades, and it can generate some well-nigh impenetrable errors. Use either `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: Please do tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use the `subfigure` package: It was last updated in 2002 and has been considered deprecated and obsolete for more than a decade by now. Use either `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: What orientation did you want? We don't have `fig.jpg` and we don't know your class. We can't know what you see ....

Comment: Maybe the image is really 4x3 and the supposed view of the original elsewhere is the rotated display.  Anyway, you can always correct the orientation with some like   `\includegraphics[ angle=90, width= .... `.